# How to build your own CMD using C++?

Tags: c++, cmd

Recently I want to enhance CMD in Win10 by myself using C++. I don't want to change the original framework of it but to *translate* the command. At first i wrote something like this:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string initial = "retr0@ ";
    string s;
    while(1)
    {
        cout << initial;
        getline(cin,s);
        if(s!="exit")
        {
            system(s.c_str());
            cout << "------" << endl;
        }
        else break;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

But I found that if you entered command like "E:" or something else to change the directory, it is impossible for the new thread to inherit the context. My question is, how to solve the problem like this?

Comment: Did you consider switching to som [Linux distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution) ? It is common practice to choose (or even code) some [command shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) on it. And Linux is very developer friendly and mostly made of [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) that you can study and improve. You could be very happy using Linux

Comment: I'd like to code it in Ubuntu 16.04 if it would be a meaningful coding experience :P (though i'm afraid that i would run into trouble in an OS that i am not familiar with).

Comment: You have a lot more documentation for Linux than for Windows, and Linux is free software, so you can study the source code

Comment: ok, i will try my best to do that :) Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most operating systems (including 1970 era Unix), the [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) is specific to each [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)).

The `system` function will run *another* process. So even if you change its working directory, it only affects the process started by `system`, not the process running your program.

So you need to define a syntax (perhaps the same `cd` as Windows CMD has) and parse and implement that command in your own program. You could use [`SetCurrentDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363806(v=vs.85).aspx) or [`_chdir`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/chdir-wchdir)

Comment: What should i do if i want to implement it? (like using other functions...)

Comment: You just need to code a [command interpreter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Command-line_interpreter). FWIW, on Unix and Linux most [unix shells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) are [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) whose source code you can study and improve. You probably could find (perhaps on [github](http://github.com/)...) some command interpreter for Windows. But I never used Windows so cannot help more (I am using Linux since 1993)